# Deploy python package but not for Windows

Tags: setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I'd like to release a version 2 of my python project to pypi but it is not Windows compatible.
The v1 is already on pypi and supports all OSes.

Is it possible to specify in the `setup.py` that this new release is not available on Windows ?

In other word, all I want is `pip install my-pkg` to install:

- v2 on Linux and Mac
- v1 on Windows

Thanks you!

Comment: Pretty sure this will just work. Pip will look for the latest version supported on the current platform and select v1 for windows.

Comment: And this is why I left Windows when developing Python apps.  And, that includes WSL2.0 (my first transition) because ... Cisco AnyConnect blocks WSL2.0 (but not WSL1.0).  I write a lot of aws cdk and hit several Windows only bugs.  One is now fixed, but still enshrined at aws cdk github site.

Comment: This will not "just work", it depends on what exactly you are uploading to PyPI. If you upload source dists, `pip` will try to install them regardless of the target platform (AFAIK you also can't restrict the target platform in the setup script), so you can't upload those. If you upload no purelib wheels (so not `py3-none-any` wheels), you should be fine; otherwise, you have to restrict the platform in the compatibility tag.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought as well. I'm afraid the only way to do it is to not upload sdist but only the platform targeted wheels.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write clear documentation to instruct your Windows users to call:

```
python -m  pip install 'my-pkg<2'
```